# Why $rank(C|_V)\geq rank(C)$ for $r$-rank preserving subspace for depth 3 circuits

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

I was reading [Deterministic Black Box PIT Testing for Generalized Depth 3 Arithmetic Circuits - Karnin and Shpilka](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Eshpilka/publications/KarninShpilka_BB_PIT.pdf)

> In the **Theorem 3.4** they told $rank(C|_V)\geq rank(C)$

We have $C|_V$ which is simple (i.e. $sim(C|_V)=C|_V$) and minimal and $C|_V\equiv 0$. Since $C\in\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is closed with respect to $V$, we have $C|_V\in\mathcal{F}$. Now since $V$ is $R_{\mathcal{F}}$-rank preserving  subspace. By the assumption we have $rank(C|_V)<R_{\mathcal{F}}$. And by the definition of $R_{\mathcal{F}}$-rank preserving subspace We have $$rank(sim(C|_V))\geq \min\{rank(sim(C)),R_{\mathcal{F}}\}\implies rank(C|_V)\geq \min\{rank(sim(C)),R_{\mathcal{F}}\}$$ since $$rank(C|_V)<R_{\mathcal{F}}$$ we have $$R_{\mathcal{F}}>rank(C|_V)\geq rank(sim(C))$$ But how are we getting $rank(C|_V)\geq rank(C)$ ?

If this is true that means $rank(C)=rank(sim(C))$ which seems false. Then how $rank(C)$ is coming up ?

Comment: Can you break your last sentence down into multiple sentences?  That is quite a lot to pack into one sentence.

Comment: Have you read the proof in the paper?  I suggest you study that proof and ask a more specific question about some aspect of the proof that you don't understand.  What is the first statement in the proof that you don't understand?  I suggest you summarize your understanding of the proof and articulate a specific question about one key claim in the proof or aspect of the proof that you are struggling with.

Comment: @D.W. my question is how we got $rank(C|_V)\geq rank(C)$. All i am getting is $rank(C|_V)\geq rank(sim(C))$

Comment: Please don't respond in the comments.  Please [edit] your question to improve it based on the feedback.  The post still contains a very long sentence ("Since...how are we getting..?").   I suggest you break that down into multiple pieces.  I also suggest that you follow the other advice in my second comment and use that to improve the question.

Comment: I tried to summarize the part I didn't understand, making it easier to read.